# How can a token holder create a 12 character account name on EOS for free?

Tags: account-name

I believe it's possible to start creating 12 character account names on EOS already. If true, what are the steps to create a free account name?

Answer (score 2):

It takes an existing account on the EOS main net in order to create a new one.

You can create one using `cleos` by Block One or if you prefer a GUI interface you can use this toolkit by [Genereos.io](https://toolkit.genereos.io/tools).

[Short video guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXXa-zwBBFM)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an EOS account yet, you need to go through an account creation tool like the one I built: https://eos-account-creator.com/